# How to get the value of an option element with a forward slash using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a `select` element with multiple options like this one:
`<option value="test/foobar">test/foobar</option>`
When i try to get the value of this via
`var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;`
all works fine as long as the value does not contain a `/` if there is one inside this value the content of `selectedValue` is only `test` and not `test/foobar` like i expect it to be.

How can I get the complete value with the `/` without jQuery?

Comment: can you control what values go into that option? Then think about using `&frasl;` maybe? You could then replace and escape it in js.

Comment: I can control what goes in there yes. But I need the slash there :U

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me.

`select` input looks like this.

```
<select id="selector">
    <option value="test/foobar1">test/foobar1</option>
    <option value="test/foobar2">test/foobar2</option>
</select>
```

js looks like this.

```
var e = document.getElementById("selector");
var selectedVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(selectedVal);
```

Comment: I just checked it with the console log. You are right. It seems the web socket which receives and sends it back is the problem here.

Comment: I you send this to server, maybe you need to encode the value using encodeURIComponent function.